# Being able to write/type different texts using each hand respectively, at the same time?

Tags: brain, behaviour, intelligence

Has there been any documentation of being able to either write down (jot down) or type in (key in) different texts using the left hand and the right hand respectively, simultaneously?

So, I'm interested in whether or not it has been documented that certain individuals can do this, and I would be greatly interested in any literature on the subject. For example, have there been any pedagogics who have argued this exercise would be beneficial for the development of individuals?

***Note:*** Of course, many people could do this, if they would do it extremely slowly; so obviously I am interested in the maximum velocity.

***See also:*** [Being able to read one text in braille using sense of touch and, at the same time, read another text visually?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54831/being-able-to-read-one-text-in-braille-using-sense-of-touch-and-at-the-same-tim)

Comment: If so I'd also be curious to know if said texts were arbitrary, since some, or perhaps even many, people could probably learn to type a very specific sequence quickly with a lot of practice. Also curious to know about keystroke timings, I imagine the ability to type two texts completely independently is very different than, say, alternating keystrokes. Former is much more multitasking, latter is coordination. For instance, one who can type on a regular keyboard effectively with either hand could imagine both hands were on the same keyboard and type arbitrary msgs, but that's not impressive.

Comment: US President James Garfield is the first person who pops into my mind. I believe Leonardo da Vinci also could, but I might be wrong...